# Automorphisms of field generated by two coprime elements

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

I would like to know if the follwing statement is true: Let $F$ be a field and let $a,b$ be algebraic over $F$ with coprime degrees $m$ and $n$, respectively. Suppose $F(b)/F$ is normal. Letting $K = F(a,b)$ and using the notation $G(M/L) = \textrm{Aut}(M/L)$, the map
$$\varphi : G(K/F(a)) \to G(F(b)/F)$$
given by $\varphi(\sigma) = \sigma \restriction_{F(b)}$ is an isomorphism.

We must first show $\varphi(\sigma) \in G(F(b)/F)$. Let $\beta \in F(b)$ with minimal polynomial $m(x)$. Then $m(\sigma(\beta)) = 0$, hence $\sigma(\beta) \in F(b)$ since $F(b)$ is normal. Clearly $\varphi(\sigma)$ is an $F$-homomorphism, so $\varphi(\sigma) \in G(F(b)/F)$.

Let $\sigma,\tau \in G(K(F(a))$. We have
$$\varphi(\sigma \circ \tau) = (\sigma \circ \tau)\restriction_{F(b)} = \sigma\restriction_{F(b)} \circ \tau\restriction_{F(b)} = \varphi(\sigma) \circ \varphi(\tau),$$
so $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. It remains to show that $\varphi$ is bijective.

Let $\tau \in G(F(b)/F)$. If $\tau(b) = \beta$, then since $m$ and $n$ are coprime, we may define $\sigma : K \to K$ by $\sigma(b) = \beta$ and $\sigma(a) = a$ so that $\sigma \in G(K/F(a)$. Then $\varphi(\sigma) = \tau$. Suppose $\varphi(\sigma) = \textrm{id}_{F(b)}$. Then $\sigma(b) = b$ and $\sigma(a) = a$, hence $\sigma = \textrm{id}_{K}$.

Is this correct? If not, can I modify the hypotheses a bit to get a true statement? Thanks.